# Increasing size of android application

Tags: android, api, performance

i am beginner in android development. I developed a meme app in Kotlin which make Api call and Api return meme i use volley library for api call and glide library for image loading. my app size is 13.3 mb I used this app for some time and after checked size of app. it was showing 200+ mb

why it is happening? How can i handle it?

it's xml code

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/memeimg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        />


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shrebutton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="15dp"
        android:paddingVertical="5dp"
        android:text="share"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="#FF7300"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline2"
        android:onClick="sharememe"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextbtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="15dp"
        android:paddingVertical="10dp"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:background="#FF7300"
        android:onClick="nextmeme"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />
```

it's kotlin code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var image:ImageView
    lateinit var progressBar:ProgressBar
    lateinit var Url:String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        image=findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.memeimg)
        progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progressbar)
        loadmeme()

    }


    fun loadmeme() {

        progressBar.visibility=View.VISIBLE

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme"

        val jsonrequest = JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,null,
            Response.Listener{ response ->
                Url=response.getString("url")
                Glide.with(this).load(Url).listener(object :RequestListener<Drawable>{

                    override fun onLoadFailed(
                        e: GlideException?,
                        model: Any?,
                        target: Target<Drawable>?,
                        isFirstResource: Boolean
                    ): Boolean {
                        progressBar.visibility=View.GONE
                        return false
                    }

                    override fun onResourceReady(
                        resource: Drawable?,
                        model: Any?,
                        target: Target<Drawable>?,
                        dataSource: DataSource?,
                        isFirstResource: Boolean
                    ): Boolean {
                        progressBar.visibility=View.GONE
                        return false
                    }

                }).into(image)
            },
            { }
        )

        queue.add(jsonrequest)
    }


        fun sharememe(view: View) {
            val intent=Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            intent.type="text/plain"
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Check out this $Url")
            val chooser=Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share this meme using...")
            startActivity(chooser)
        }

        fun nextmeme(view: View) {
            loadmeme()
        }
}
```

Comment: It's because the images are getting cached. So when you open the app again, Glide will just load from memory instead of re-loading the whole stuff using Internet.

Comment: yes it works but my app become very slow now